# Button decrement method

Tags: java, android

I have a "-". It is linked with a decrement method which just decreases the quantity by 1. And if quantity is already is 1 then it shows a Toast... But I can't get the toast and the quantity is going in -1 if I press the button at 1.

```
public void decrement(View view) {

    if(quantity == 1){
        Toast.makeText(this, "You can order a min of 1 Coffees", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    quantity = quantity - 1;
    displayQuantity(quantity);
}
```

If quantity is already is 1 then it shows a Toast... But I can't get the toast and the quantity is going in -1 if I press the button at 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void decrement(View view) {
    if(quantity > 1){
        quantity = quantity - 1;
        displayQuantity(quantity);
    } else if(quantity == 1){
        Toast.makeText(this, "You can order a min of 1 Coffees", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    } else{
        // do nothing
    }
}
```